# Sunspot and Solr: Google-like "site:" in search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot

I'm fairly new to Sunspot and Solr.

I'd like to implement something similar to the Google `site:` phrase in searches, so that when I search for

> something

I get all records related to "something". However, if they search

> something site:example.com

It only displays results where the `site` attribute is `example.com`.

At the moment I've got:

```
searchable do
    text :full_text
    text :title, :boost => 5
    text :excerpt
end
```

Do I need to index the `site` attribute? How would I implement the above idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Just make sure you gsub your params[:query] in your controller. Extract the value next to site: and add a where close to match the site. You'll be left with `something`.